# Comparing linear time strongly connected component algorithms in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, comparative-review, graph

So I have implemented three linear time (\$\mathcal{O}(V + E)\$) algorithms for finding [strongly connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component) of a (directed) graph. A strongly connected component is just a maximal subset of nodes, such that any node in the subset can be reached from any other node in the subset.

The algorithms I am comparing are:

1. [Kosaraju](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosaraju%27s_algorithm),
2. [Tarjan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm),
3. [Path-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path-based_strong_component_algorithm).

See below for code.

**SCCFinder.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.graph.scc;

import java.util.List;
import net.coderodde.graph.DirectedGraph;

/**
 * This interface defines the API for algorithms finding strongly connected 
 * components.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (May 3, 2016)
 */
public interface SCCFinder {

    /**
     * Returns a list of strongly connected components in the input graph
     * {@code digraph}.
     * 
     * @param digraph
     * @return 
     */
    public List<List<Integer>> 
        findStronglyConnectedCmponents(final DirectedGraph digraph);
}
```

**KosarajuSCCFinder.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.graph.scc.support;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;
import net.coderodde.graph.DirectedGraph;
import net.coderodde.graph.scc.SCCFinder;

/**
 * This class implements the recursive
 * <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosaraju%27s_algorithm">Kosarajus's
 * algorithm</a>
 * for finding strongly connected components in an input directed graph.
 *
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (May 3, 2016)
 */
public final class KosarajuSCCFinder implements SCCFinder {

    private DirectedGraph digraph;
    private List<Integer> nodeList;
    private Set<Integer> visitedSet;
    private Map<Integer, Integer> assignmentMap;

    public KosarajuSCCFinder() {}

    private KosarajuSCCFinder(final DirectedGraph digraph) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(digraph, "The input directed graph is null.");
        this.digraph = digraph;
        this.nodeList = new ArrayList<>(digraph.size());
        this.visitedSet = new HashSet<>(digraph.size());
        this.assignmentMap = new HashMap<>(digraph.size());
    }

    @Override
    public List<List<Integer>>
            findStronglyConnectedCmponents(DirectedGraph digraph) {
        return new KosarajuSCCFinder(digraph).compute();
    }

    private List<List<Integer>> compute() {
        for (final Integer node : digraph.getAllNodes()) {
            visit(node);
        }

        Collections.<Integer>reverse(nodeList);

        for (final Integer node : nodeList) {
            assign(node, node);
        }

        final Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();

        for (final Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry
                : assignmentMap.entrySet()) {
            final Integer component = entry.getValue();

            if (!map.containsKey(component)) {
                map.put(component, new ArrayList<>());
            }

            map.get(component).add(entry.getKey());
        }

        return new ArrayList<>(map.values());
    }

    private void visit(final Integer node) {
        if (visitedSet.contains(node)) {
            return;
        }

        visitedSet.add(node);

        for (final Integer child : digraph.getChildrenOf(node)) {
            visit(child);
        }

        nodeList.add(node);
    }

    private void assign(final Integer node, final Integer root) {
        if (!assignmentMap.containsKey(node)) {
            assignmentMap.put(node, root);

            for (final Integer parent : digraph.getParentsOf(node)) {
                assign(parent, root);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**TarjanSCCFinder.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.graph.scc.support;

import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;
import net.coderodde.graph.DirectedGraph;
import net.coderodde.graph.scc.SCCFinder;

/**
 * This class implements 
 * <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm">Tarjan's strongly connected components algorithm</a> using 
 * recursive depth-first search.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (May 3, 2016)
 */
public final class TarjanSCCFinder implements SCCFinder {

    private DirectedGraph digraph;
    private int index;
    private Deque<Integer> stack;
    private Set<Integer> onStackSet;
    private Map<Integer, Integer> indexMap;
    private Map<Integer, Integer> lowLinkMap;
    private List<List<Integer>> solution;

    public TarjanSCCFinder() {}

    private TarjanSCCFinder(final DirectedGraph digraph) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(digraph, "The input digraph is null.");
        this.digraph = digraph;
        this.stack = new ArrayDeque<>();
        this.indexMap = new HashMap<>();
        this.lowLinkMap = new HashMap<>();
        this.onStackSet = new HashSet<>();
        this.solution = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public List<List<Integer>> 
        findStronglyConnectedCmponents(final DirectedGraph digraph) {
        return new TarjanSCCFinder(digraph).compute();
    }

    private List<List<Integer>> compute() {
        Objects.requireNonNull(digraph, "The input directed graph is null.");

        for (final Integer node : digraph.getAllNodes()) {
            if (!indexMap.containsKey(node)) {
                strongConnect(node);
            }
        }

        return this.solution;
    }

    private void strongConnect(final Integer node) {
        indexMap.put(node, index);
        lowLinkMap.put(node, index);
        ++index;
        stack.push(node);
        onStackSet.add(node);

        for (final Integer child : digraph.getChildrenOf(node)) {

            if (!indexMap.containsKey(child)) {
                strongConnect(child);
                lowLinkMap.put(node, Math.min(lowLinkMap.get(node), 
                                              lowLinkMap.get(child)));
            } else if (onStackSet.contains(child)) {
                lowLinkMap.put(node, Math.min(lowLinkMap.get(node), 
                                              indexMap.get(child)));
            }
        }

        if (lowLinkMap.get(node).equals(indexMap.get(node))) {
            final List<Integer> newStronglyConnectedComponent = 
                    new ArrayList<>();

            Integer top;

            do {
                top = stack.pop();
                onStackSet.remove(top);
                newStronglyConnectedComponent.add(top);
            } while (!top.equals(node));

            this.solution.add(newStronglyConnectedComponent);
        }
    }
}
```

**PathBasedSCCFinder.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.graph.scc.support;

import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;
import net.coderodde.graph.DirectedGraph;
import net.coderodde.graph.scc.SCCFinder;

/**
 * This class implements a <a href="">path-based strong component algorithm</a>.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6
 */
public class PathBasedSCCFinder implements SCCFinder {

    private DirectedGraph digraph;
    private int counter;
    private Set<Integer> assignedNodeSet;
    private Map<Integer, Integer> preorderNumberMap;
    private Deque<Integer> stackP;
    private Deque<Integer> stackS;
    private List<List<Integer>> solution;

    public PathBasedSCCFinder() {}

    private PathBasedSCCFinder(final DirectedGraph digraph) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(digraph, "The input directed graph is null.");
        this.digraph = digraph;
        this.assignedNodeSet = new HashSet<>();
        this.preorderNumberMap = new HashMap<>();
        this.stackP = new ArrayDeque<>();
        this.stackS = new ArrayDeque<>();
        this.solution = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public List<List<Integer>> 
    findStronglyConnectedCmponents(DirectedGraph digraph) {
        return new PathBasedSCCFinder(digraph).compute();
    }

    private List<List<Integer>> compute() {
        for (final Integer node : digraph.getAllNodes()) {
            if (!preorderNumberMap.containsKey(node)) {
                visit(node);
            }
        }

        return this.solution;
    }

    private void visit(final Integer node) {
        preorderNumberMap.put(node, counter++);
        stackP.addLast(node);
        stackS.addLast(node);

        for (final Integer child : digraph.getChildrenOf(node)) {
            if (!preorderNumberMap.containsKey(child)) {
                visit(child);
            } else if (!assignedNodeSet.contains(child)) {
                while (preorderNumberMap.get(stackP.getLast()) > 
                       preorderNumberMap.get(child)) {
                    stackP.removeLast();
                }
            }
        }

        if (node.equals(stackP.getLast())) {
            stackP.removeLast();
            Integer topOfStackS;
            final List<Integer> component = new ArrayList<>();

            do {
                topOfStackS = stackS.removeLast();
                component.add(topOfStackS);
                assignedNodeSet.add(topOfStackS);
            } while (!topOfStackS.equals(node));

            this.solution.add(component);
        }
    }
}
```

**DirectedGraph.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.graph;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * This class implements a directed graph.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Jan 11, 2016)
 */
public class DirectedGraph {

    private int edges;

    private final Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> parentMap = new HashMap<>();
    private final Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> childMap  = new HashMap<>();

    public int size() {
        return parentMap.size();
    }

    public int getNumberOfEdges() {
        return edges;
    }

    public boolean addNode(int nodeId) {
        if (parentMap.containsKey(nodeId)) {
            return false;
        }

        parentMap.put(nodeId, new HashSet<>());
        childMap .put(nodeId, new HashSet<>());
        return true;
    }

    public boolean hasNode(int nodeId) {
        return parentMap.containsKey(nodeId);
    }

    public boolean clearNode(int nodeId) {
        if (!hasNode(nodeId)) {
            return false;
        }

        Set<Integer> parents = parentMap.get(nodeId);
        Set<Integer> children = childMap.get(nodeId);

        if (parents.isEmpty() && children.isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }

        for (Integer childId : children) {
            parentMap.get(childId).remove(nodeId);
        }

        for (Integer parentId : parents) {
            childMap.get(parentId).remove(nodeId);
        }

        edges -= parents.size() + children.size();
        parents.clear();
        children.clear();
        return true;
    }

    public boolean removeNode(int nodeId) {
        if (!hasNode(nodeId)) {
            return false;
        }

        clearNode(nodeId);
        parentMap.remove(nodeId);
        childMap.remove(nodeId);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean addEdge(int tailNodeId, int headNodeId) {
        addNode(tailNodeId);
        addNode(headNodeId);

        if (childMap.get(tailNodeId).contains(headNodeId)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            childMap .get(tailNodeId).add(headNodeId);
            parentMap.get(headNodeId).add(tailNodeId);
            edges++;
            return true;
        }
    }

    public boolean hasEdge(int tailNodeId, int headNodeId) {
        if (!childMap.containsKey(tailNodeId)) {
            return false;
        }

        return childMap.get(tailNodeId).contains(headNodeId);
    }

    public boolean removeEdge(int tailNodeId, int headNodeId) {
        if (!childMap.containsKey(tailNodeId)) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!childMap.get(tailNodeId).contains(headNodeId)) {
            return false;
        }

        childMap .get(tailNodeId).remove(headNodeId);
        parentMap.get(headNodeId).remove(tailNodeId);
        edges--;
        return true;
    }

    public Set<Integer> getChildrenOf(int nodeId) {
        if (!childMap.containsKey(nodeId)) {
            return Collections.<Integer>emptySet();
        }

        return Collections.<Integer>unmodifiableSet(childMap.get(nodeId));
    }

    public Set<Integer> getParentsOf(int nodeId) {
        if (!parentMap.containsKey(nodeId)) {
            return Collections.<Integer>emptySet();
        }

        return Collections.<Integer>unmodifiableSet(parentMap.get(nodeId));
    }

    public Set<Integer> getAllNodes() {
        return Collections.<Integer>unmodifiableSet(childMap.keySet());
    }

    public void clear() {
        childMap.clear();
        parentMap.clear();
        edges = 0;
    }
}
```

**SCCFinderDemo.java**:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;
import net.coderodde.graph.DirectedGraph;
import net.coderodde.graph.scc.SCCFinder;
import net.coderodde.graph.scc.support.KosarajuSCCFinder;
import net.coderodde.graph.scc.support.PathBasedSCCFinder;
import net.coderodde.graph.scc.support.TarjanSCCFinder;

public class SCCFinderDemo {

    private static final class DEMO_DATA {
        private static final int NODES = 100_000;
        private static final int ARCS  = 150_000;
    }

    private static final class WARMUP_DATA {
        private static final int NODES = 5_000;
        private static final int ARCS  = 80_000;
        private static final int ITERATIONS = 50;
    }

    private static final class FINDERS {
        static SCCFinder KOSARAJU   = new KosarajuSCCFinder();
        static SCCFinder TARJAN     = new TarjanSCCFinder();
        static SCCFinder PATH_BASED = new PathBasedSCCFinder();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final long seed = System.nanoTime();
        final Random random = new Random(seed);

        System.out.println("Seed = " + seed);
        System.out.println("[STATUS] Warming up...");

        warmup(random);

        System.out.println("[STATUS] Warming done.");

        final DirectedGraph digraph = createRandomDigraph(random,
                                                          DEMO_DATA.NODES,
                                                          DEMO_DATA.ARCS);
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        final List<List<Integer>> scc1 = 
                FINDERS.KOSARAJU.findStronglyConnectedCmponents(digraph);
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();

        System.out.printf("Kosaraju's algorithm in %d milliseconds.\n",
                          (endTime - startTime) / 1_000_000);

        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        final List<List<Integer>> scc2 = 
                FINDERS.TARJAN.findStronglyConnectedCmponents(digraph);
        endTime = System.nanoTime();

        System.out.printf("Tarjan's algorithm in %d milliseconds.\n",
                          (endTime - startTime) / 1_000_000);

        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        final List<List<Integer>> scc3 = 
                FINDERS.PATH_BASED.findStronglyConnectedCmponents(digraph);
        endTime = System.nanoTime();

        System.out.printf("Path-based algorithm in %d milliseconds.\n",
                          (endTime - startTime) / 1_000_000);

        // We need to sort each strongly connected component so that we can
        // ask whether two are same.
        for (final List<Integer> component : scc1) {
            Collections.sort(component);
        }

        for (final List<Integer> component : scc2) {
            Collections.sort(component);
        }

        for (final List<Integer> component : scc3) {
            Collections.sort(component);
        }

        // Sets ignore the order so that we don't need to sort the components.
        final Set<List<Integer>> scc1set = new HashSet<>(scc1);
        final Set<List<Integer>> scc2set = new HashSet<>(scc2);
        final Set<List<Integer>> scc3set = new HashSet<>(scc3);

        System.out.println("---");
        System.out.println("Algorithms agree: " + (scc1set.equals(scc2set) && 
                                                   scc2set.equals(scc3set)));
    }

    private static void warmup(final Random random) {
        final DirectedGraph digraph = 
                createRandomDigraph(random,
                                    WARMUP_DATA.NODES,
                                    WARMUP_DATA.ARCS);

        for (int i = 0; i < WARMUP_DATA.ITERATIONS; ++i) {
            FINDERS.KOSARAJU  .findStronglyConnectedCmponents(digraph);
            FINDERS.TARJAN    .findStronglyConnectedCmponents(digraph);
            FINDERS.PATH_BASED.findStronglyConnectedCmponents(digraph);
        }
    }

    private static DirectedGraph createRandomDigraph(final Random random,
                                                     final int nodes,
                                                     final int arcs) {
        final DirectedGraph digraph = new DirectedGraph();

        for (int i = 0; i < nodes; ++i) {
            digraph.addNode(i);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < arcs; ++i) {
            digraph.addEdge(random.nextInt(nodes), random.nextInt(nodes));
        }

        return digraph;
    }
}
```

The performance figures are as follows:

```
Kosaraju's algorithm in 1253 milliseconds.
Tarjan's algorithm in 287 milliseconds.
Path-based algorithm in 243 milliseconds.
---
Algorithms agree: true
```

I would be glad to hear comments about API design, naming, coding conventions and warming up the JVM; however, any critique is much appreciated.

**IMPORTANT** Please pass the **`-Xss20m`** option to the JVM. Otherwise you will get a stack overflow since the demo graph is large, and all the algorithms are recursive.

Comment: I have a `StackOverflowError` when I try to run the code in the question. Did you change the stack size? Edit: it appears to work with `-Xss4m`.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning. I completely forgot to make a note that people should order JVM a larger stack. I added the note in the end of my question. Thanks again!